# how to set value of simple form checkbox to String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i have checkbox in simple form:

```
= f.input :status, as: :boolean
```

but i don't want values to be 0 or 1. i want them to be Strings, like eg 'not_done' and 'completed'. how can i achieve that?
i ran into some kind of solution on github thread, but i don't really know what is it doing, plus, it always give me "new" as value, doesnt matter if the field is checked or not...

```
= f.input :status, as: :boolean do
    - f.check_box :status, {}, "new", "confirmed"
```

Comment: The "check_box" method should work: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box. You don't need the first "f.input". Just the checkbox.

Comment: but how it is supposed to look like, doc isnt it really making it clear for me with the arguments...:/

Comment: Kuba, it should look exactly like it already does: `f.check_box :Status, {}, "new", "confirmed"`. But *just* that part. Completely get rid of the `f.input :status`. That is shadowing the checkbox result.

Comment: tried it, and it is giving me value: "new" whether it is checked or not

Comment: you can use option box instead

Comment: Ban Lee, you were right at the very beginning, check_box method works;]

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
<%= f.input :status, as: :boolean,
                     checked_value: 'completed',
                     unchecked_value: 'not_done'
                     %>
```

This will set the values as `completed` when checked and `not_done` when unchecked.

However, if you want to go ahead and display the same, you can do:

```
<%= f.input :status, as: :boolean,
                     checked_value: 'completed',
                     unchecked_value: 'not_done',
                     input_html: {
                       name: 'status_checkbox', # not a must, will help for identification and testing
                       checked: params[:status] == 'completed' ? 'Completed' : 'Not Done'
                     } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with check_box then its possible:

```
<%= f.input :status, :as => :check_boxes, collection: [['Completed', 'completed']]  %>
```

But you should not expect two values from a check_box. It will carry only one value. the reverse will be considered if the check box is not checked.

Comment: this solution doesnt give me no value at all in check box...:/

Comment: here is the out put html:

`<ol class="choices-group">
<li class="choice">
<label for="object_status_completed">
<input id="object_status_completed" type="checkbox" value="completed" name="object[status][]">
Completed
</label>
</li>
</ol>`

Comment: and what am i supposed do with it?:)

Comment: ok, i was wrong, it does give me value, but it is always the same value

Comment: you can use option box if you need multiple values

Comment: <input class="check_boxes optional" id="company_day_status_not_completed" name="company_day[status][]" type="checkbox" value="Not_completed"> HTML here, what do you mean by code, to the view i just copied your answer

Comment: I can see the value is set as "Not_completed"